# Add a new value on a relation list between users and a table

Tags: cloudboost

**SOLVED**

The situation is that I have two tables, the table *User* that CloudBoost gives you, and the table *Movie* that I made up. *User* contains a list called *movies* for the relation, being a relation many to many.

What I want to make is to add a new movie to the list of movies that the user already have. That's what I thought it should work:

```
var user = CB.CloudUser.current;
var movies = user.get("movies");
movies.push(movie);
user.set('movies', movies);
user.save({
  success : function(user){
    //do things
  }, error : function(err){
    //do things
  }
});
```

However, it cannot make the `user.save`, it bumps an error.

How could I made this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I came up with was simply to put the relation list on the *Movie* table and not on the *User* one. This implies more queries and more code, but at the end it's what works.